# can't access my bios with my usb keyboard no ps/2

Tags: usb, keyboard, bios, post, ps2

my USB keyboard doesn't seem to be recognized at post. I have no ps/2 port. no port on my motherboard. Can't install my windows 7 cause I think is on gpt or else. I really need to get access to my bios. cause my hard disk is fully formated

need help please

Comment: Is the keyboard wired? Try another keyboard?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your keyboard is plugged in at the rear USB ports. These ports are initalised first during post and they should allow you to get into the bios.

I often start pressing the escape key during boot which somehow seems to help getting my keyboard activated quicker. If it doesn't get the keyboard active in time, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>delete</kbd> as soon as it allows you to reboot the pc. Chances are that the keyboard is much quicker initialised so you can get into the bios in time.